# How to retrieve Twitter search results dynamically using Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, api, search, twitter

I'm building a Twitter application which depends on retrieving Twitter search results. It works fine but I still need to update the page to get the new tweets.

How to let the page refreshes itself dynamically just like Twitter Widgets, to show the new tweets ?

Here is my code, please show me how, because I tired many scripts and it doesn't work with me.

Twitter Class

```
<?php

class Twitter
{
    public function __construct(){  }

    public function searchResults( $search = null )
    {
        $url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=" . urlencode( $search ) . "&lang=en&rpp=50";
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
        $result = curl_exec( $curl );
        curl_close( $curl );

        $return = new SimpleXMLElement( $result );
        return $return;
        }
    }
?>
```

Test Class

```
<?php


require_once("twitter.class.php");
$Twitter = new Twitter;

$results = $Twitter->searchResults("usa");

foreach( $results->entry as $result )
{
    echo "<h3><a href=\"". $result->author->uri ."\">". $result->author->name ."<a/></h3><img src=\"". $result->link[1]->attributes()->href ."\" style=\"float: left;\"><p>". $result->content."</p><div style=\"clear:both;\">&nbsp;</div>";
}
?>
```

.
.

Waiting for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

You could poll for changes through javascript / ajax, by setting up a timer that calls a function in Test Class which returns a list of tweets. Example (using jquery because I am no javascript expert):

```
$(function() {

    function fetchTweets() {

        $.ajax({
          url: "testclass.php",
          success: function(data) {

            // Replace contents of one element with data
        }
    }

    setInterval(fetchTweets(), 60000);
}
```

Comment: This code would go in a script block within the head section of the html which makes up the page. The file name testclass.php should point to the file name of TestClass and the value 60000 is the time delay between updates in milliseconds.